# How to use XQuery in DotNet

Tags: c#, xquery, xquery-3.0

I am developing project for that i want to apply some xqueries on XML file and get the data from XML, but i don't understand how to use XQuery in dotnet. Is there any alternative for XQuery in dotnet

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried LINQ to XML? That is pretty good way to go. You can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is an alternative. It is called "linq-to-xml". For some information, start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/bb387098.aspx).